# Have both local and puppet managed users on linux

Tags: puppet

We manage users via puppet on our ubuntu servers. So any user not managed via puppet(i.e. created locally) is being removed when the host is being puppetized. Is this the expected behaviour of puppet? If yes, can this be turned off?

Comment: Are you by any chance defining a template for /etc/passwd? Could you show us your Puppet manifest? This is not the expected behavior.

Comment: Without adding the puppet manifest it is impossible to answer the question.

Comment: `So any user not managed via puppet(i.e. created locally) is being removed when the host is being puppetized.`. If puppet is run then it is not normal that users are removed. It is dependent on how the manifests look like